# HTML5 Drag and Drop, Or JqueryUI Drag and Drop?

Tags: html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I'm developing a client-side application.
It doesn't need to be cross-browser.
And also I wanna use drag and drop feature.

I'm familiar with JqueryUI Drag and drop, But I wanna know which one is better in performance and easy programming, Html5, or JqueryUI?

thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recently made an application which lets users drag and drop hundreds of items (with lots of CSS) between hundreds of lists (drop zones) and I experienced horrible performance with jQuery. I then changed over to HTML5 Drag and Drop API and since the whole thing runs smoothly even on 1st Gen Centrinos. No wonder, as native code is used.

The HTML5 API needs to get used to since it's generally written with non-mouse-controlled devices in mind as well, but the results are not more complicated then jQuery UI code.

So as a conclusion I think sticking with jQuery UI is ok when you have only a small number of items to drag. I also expect jQuery UI to use the HTML5 API internally some time in future so you might get that benefit of native code automatically by upgrading to another jQuery version.

Answer (score 3):

Although Jquery UI gives additional functionality but in many scenarios we dont need them which in turn becomes heavy and on the other hand HTML5 Drag and Drop API is smooth and light.

So its upto user : if you want additional functionalities go for Jquery UI otherwise Opt HTML5 Drag and Drop

-Mohit

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest you to use JqueryUI. Its more flexible. Will be easier in future for you to improve it. I never used HTML5 drag and drop and didn't knew that it exist. So I can't compare them, but I think jQuery will be better.